# Select return no result

Tags: c#, sqlite

In my database I have a table called `books`, actually there is one record.

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  | Alice in Wonderland
```

I want select all the records available, so I did:

```
var m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM Books";
var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection );
SQLiteDataReader reader = command .ExecuteReader();
```

the `reader` return no result. Why?

Comment: what do u mean it return no result ?

Comment: It is _command.ExecuteReader_. Not _DBCommand.ExecuteReader_ right?

Comment: Think you need to change DBCommand to use command.ExecuteReader.  You are not executing the reader using your command

Comment: Take a real close look at the last 2 lines of your code....

Comment: and why is your SqlLiteCommand name different than the declared one ?

Comment: `m_dbConnection` is what u declared u sql connection with , but in sql command u use `DBConnection` , are u writing pusedo codes ?

Comment: Now consider that you have no path on the database name in your connection string. This means that the code uses the database in the current working directory. When you run inside VS in a debug session this directory is the BIN\DEBUG one. So check if the database in that location contains the expected records

Comment: Don't you need to pass `m_dbConnection` to the `SQLiteCommand` constructor?

Comment: re-check your database

Comment: You're not reading the results of the `DataReader` anywhere in this code. Where does it say `the enumeration did not return results` ?

Comment: @Unguenguengueéosas,check my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: You have to call `reader.Read()` for each row in the result set. You might want to brush up on the docs for how to use a `IDataReader`.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield , it is not necessary.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right **database**?

Comment: @JuanR yes because if I use a DataTable as zack suggested I get the row, but if I use the reader I don't get the rows. Unfortunately I got 4 downvotes and I didn't know why, maybe some users simply do not want to apply so they put downvote

Comment: I see. I think the downvotes might have been a result of the original quality of your question/code sample.

Comment: Have you tried opening the connection **after** you create the command?

Comment: I open the connection after create that.. I'm not stupid. I followed this tutorial: http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Comment: No one is calling you stupid. I am trying to help you. It should make no difference where you open the connection but it's worth trying if everything else fails. Instead of opening it right after you create the connection object, try opening it after you create the command. Maybe it will make a difference.

Comment: Try assigning a full path to the database file. Also, make sure the SqlLite database is not version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show where you display the data or where the exception is thrown.However,try `SqlLiteCommand.Prepare` method:

```
 var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection );
 command.Prepare();

 ///and use While statement for the reader

While dr.read
{
 }
```

If this doesn't work , just try a `Datatable` and see if results are same(though it doesn't make any difference at all) :

```
SqLiteDataAdapter ada = new SqliteDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable;

ada.Fill(dt);
myDataGridView.Datasource=dt;

///or

string vale = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString;
```

Comment: This answer provides a workaround but does not address the real problem. dr(0) is not the same in C#.

Comment: @JuanR, i agree tha i should've wrote `dr[0]` and i don't know why the OP is having this issue as this is very ODD to me , but i suggested him to use `command.Prepare` which helps sometimes